# what is the rolling_pts parameter in differential_drive?

Tags: ros, differential-drive

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

What does the rolling points parameter mean in the [differential_drive](http://wiki.ros.org/differential_drive/) package? Is is robot specific? and how do I obtain it for my robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215525/what-is-the-rolling_pts-parameter-in-differential_drive?/) by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This isn't clear in the code, and took a little reading around, but `rolling_pts` is used in the [pid_velocity.py](http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/differential_drive/html/pid__velocity_8py_source.html) file to set how many past velocity measurements are used to calculate the average velocity. For example, setting `rolling_pts` to 2 will make PID controller average the 2 latest velocity measurements to create what it considers the "current velocity".

The name is a little misleading, but now that I know what it does, it is called "rolling" because it is a [rolling average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average). I assume this is done because only using the single latest velocity measurement, instead of an average, could be a bit noisy in some situations, so using the average smooths things out a bit.

p.s. the way I figured this all out was a reference to `rolling_pts` in this slightly related [page](http://mobilerobots.case.edu/mirror/roswiki/knex_ros.html).

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2015-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-08-10**:
Thank you so much! Makes sense now!